# Set value of keras variable with different shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Is it possible to update a a keras variable with a list of different shape? Something like:

```
var = K.variable([someDefault]) #shape = (1,) or any

K.set_value(var, [[1,2]]) #shape can be arbitrary
```

The  above line gives value error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 2) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1,)'
```

Comment: Why don't assign var to other value like: var = K.varaible([[1,2]])

Comment: Actually I want to use this variable as placeholder before before constructing the graph and after training I would like to pass an array to this variable (variable size) and then do some operations in call function of a custom keras layer during test phase.

Comment: You can't change the shape entirely. What you can do, however, is define the placeholder with shape `[1, -1]` to let the second dimension have an arbitrary size. Note, however, that then *all* the tensors you feed must have the same number of dimensions (and shape matching the shape pattern you choose, of course)